# Alternatives of InProc Sessions in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, user-management

I am working on .NET Core web application. I have UserDetails table storing user login credentials & other details.
 At the time of Login, after checking the user entered credentials against database table I use sessions to manage LoggedIn user details-userId,companycode etc. I need these details across the website for various operations. But it doesn't work properly on UAT as we have Load Balancers configured on Prod & UAT. 
Now I need to use some other mechanism to maintain LoggedIn User details across the requests. I am checking DistributedCache & nCache but not able to get something useful. 
What can be the secure alternatives of session to store user data?

Thanks.